# tengo una clase con dos 2 listas una de productos y otra de la cantidad de cada producto como hago un metodo donde calcule el total del precio

Tags: python

**la primera lista tiene el nombre del producto y la segunda tiene la cantidad de este producto, no entiendo como vincular cada producto de la primera lista con cada valor de la segunda lista que seria su cantidad**

class pedido:
lista_p = []
lista_c = []

```
def __init__(self, lista_p=[], lista_c=[]):
    self.lista_p = lista_p
    self.lista_c = lista_c
    print("se ha creado la lista")
```

**la unica idea que se me ocurrio fue hacer un bucle de la lista de donde multiplicada el valor del producto con la determinada posicion de la lista donde se supone que va la cantidad del producto que deseo comprar**

```
 def total_pedido(self): 
     for a in lista_c:
        if a > 0:
            t1 = lista_c[0]    * 15 **cada numero por el que multiplico cada posicion de la lista es el valor de un producto**
    
    for a in lista_c:
        if a > 0:
            t2 = lista_c[1] * 23
    
    for a in lista_c:
        if a > 0:
            t3 = lista_c[2] * 50
            
    for a in lista_c:
        if a > 0:
            t4 = lista_c[3] * 12
    
    return t1 + t2 + t3 + t4
```

yu = pedido(["raton", "teclado", "camara", "cargador"], [1, 3, 2, 5])

yu.total_pedido

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Para calcular el total multiplica el precio por la cantidad de cada uno y luego lo sumas